# Do a conditional $lookup depending of a value in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have three collections in MongoDB 4.0 (pymongo)

```
users: [
{name: "John", user_type: "client", society: 1},
{name: "Charles", user_type: "client", society: 1},
{name: "Jessy", user_type: "provider", society: 1},
{name: "Tim", user_type: "provider", society: 2}
]

clients: [
{_id: 1, name: "Client1"}
]

providers: [
{_id: 1, name: "Provider1"},
{_id: 2, name: "Provider2"}
]
```

I need to do a join between users and clients or providers depending on `user_type` value and set it in the same key value in the result.

For example, the result will be :

```
user : {name: "John", user_type: "client", society: 1, complete_society: {_id: 1, name: "Client1"}}

or

user : {name: "Tim", user_type: "provider", society: 2, complete_society: {_id: 2, name: "Provider2"}}
```

The only solution I have now is to do two different `$lookup` in two different key and then rework the result after the request

```
db.users.aggregate([{                                   
  "$lookup": {
    "from": "clients",
    "localField": "society",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "client"
  }
},
{"$unwind": "$clients"},{                                   
  "$lookup": {
    "from": "providers",
    "localField": "society",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "provider"
  }
},
{"$unwind": "$providers"}]);
```

And then do a forEach and set a key `complete_society` and delete previous keys. It's not the perfect way and maybe in mongo, something exists to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change your query as per below to achieve your expected result,

- remove `$unwind` stages
- `$project` to show required fields
- `$arrayElemAt` to get the first element from the result of lookup
- `$cond` to check `user_type` is "client" then return `client` array otherwise return `provider` array

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "clients",
      localField: "society",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "client"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "providers",
      localField: "society",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "provider"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      society: 1,
      user_type: 1,
      complete_society: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          {
            $cond: [{ $eq: ["$user_type", "client"] }, "$client", "$provider"]
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QmbJRRWf70o)

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, an additional question :). Aggregate give an array, but sometimes I have only one result (like an find_one), if it exists something to not do list(db.users...)[0], will appreciate

Comment: @yassinekhelifa `aggregate` method will always return an array, i don't think is there any other method to get only object.